# How make the vite react app run on http://localhost:3000 insted of http://127.0.0.1:5173

Tags: reactjs, oauth, vite

Im trying to use google oauth with my vite react app but i dont know why the Authorized JavaScript origins is not working if i give http://127.0.0.1:5173  as the URIs but its working for http://localhost:3000 so i want to make my vite react app run on http://localhost:3000 insted of http://127.0.0.1:5173 when i type `npm run dev` and press `o` (to open the page on browser).

I even tried to make some changes to the vite.config.js but still not working below is the code

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3000,
  },
});
```

In package.json file
[this is the change that i have made in package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svfsa.png)

someone please help me with this.

[Tried this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIWMK.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vite.config.ts`

```
import dns from 'dns';

// localhost part
dns.setDefaultResultOrder('verbatim');

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
});
```